# Calculating $\langle p^2 \rangle $ for a non-smooth wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

I am trying to calculate $\langle p^2 \rangle$ for the wavefunction $$ \psi(x) = \frac{\sqrt{m\alpha}}{\hbar}e^{-\frac{m\alpha\lvert x \rvert}{\hbar^2}}.$$ So far I have $$ \langle p^2 \rangle = - \hbar^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \:\psi^\ast \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\\=-m\alpha\:( \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx \:+ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{-\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx ) \\ =-m\alpha\:(\frac{m\alpha}{\hbar^2} \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\frac{d}{dx} e^{\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx \: -\frac{m\alpha}{\hbar^2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\frac{d}{dx} e^{-\frac{m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx ) \\ =-m\alpha\:(\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\hbar^4} \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\frac{2m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx \: +\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{\hbar^4} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{2m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\:dx ) \\ -m\alpha(\frac{m\alpha}{2\hbar^2} e^{\frac{2m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\rvert_{-\infty}^{0}-\frac{m\alpha}{2\hbar^2} e^{\frac{2m\alpha x}{\hbar^2}}\rvert_{0}^{\infty}) = -{(\frac{m\alpha}{\hbar})}^2,$$ which is correct side from the minus sign. I’m not sure what went wrong and whether it has anything to do with the fact that the integrated is discontinuous?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/

Comment: This is literally a "check my work" question, so will likely be closed as off-topic. Sorry. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: The second derivative $\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}$ is infinite
at $x=0$. More precisely: it has a $\delta(x)$ component, which you missed in your calculation.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Bound_state_(E_%3C_0)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed.

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function.  We say that $g$ is a distributional derivative of $f$ if, given any smooth, compactly-supported [test function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions) $\psi:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, we have that
$$\int_\mathbb R g(x) \psi(x)\mathrm dx = -\int_\mathbb R f(x) \psi'(x) \mathrm dx$$
The motivation for this definition comes from integration by parts. If $f$ is everywhere differentiable, for example, then $g=f'$ satisfies this definition (note that the boundary terms vanish because $\psi$ is compactly-supported). However, this extends the notion of differentiability to functions which don't have a traditional derivative, and distributions which are defined only under the integral sign.

In the distributional sense, we have that
$$\frac{d}{dx}|x| = \theta(x)\qquad \frac{d^2}{dx^2}|x|= \theta'(x) = 2\delta(x)$$
where $\theta$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), which can be verified straightforwardly. Employing the chain rule, we find that
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{a |x|} = a \theta(x) e^{a|x|}\qquad \frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{a|x|} = 2a\delta(x)  e^{a|x|} + a^2\theta(x)^2 e^{a|x|}= 2a\delta(x) e^{a|x|}+a^2 e^{a|x|}$$

where we've used that $\theta(x)^2=1$. The problem with your work is that you have neglected the former of the two terms on the right-hand side. Going back through with this in mind should resolve your issue.

---

Just for fun, an alternative route to the solution would be to express the integrand as the limit of a sequence of smooth functions, on which $p^2$ may act in the obvious way.  A particular property of self-adjoint operators is that they are *closed*, which means in particular that for an operator $A$ with domain $\mathrm{dom}(A)$, if a sequence $\psi_n\in \mathrm{dom}(A)$ converges to $\psi$ and the sequence $A\psi_n$ converges at all, then $A\psi_n$ converges to $A\psi$.

For example, if we let
$$e^{-a|x|} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-ax\tanh(nx)}$$
then we can say that
$$p^2 e^{-a|x|} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p^2 e^{-ax\tanh(nx)}$$

If we slog through the algebra and take the limits, we will obtain the same result as above.